# How update dynamically a form when we add a new property to the entity related

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I just read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) of Symfony about Form Events, but I don't really understand.

- How to add dynamically fields in a form when whe add or edit a new property in the entity class ?

---

For example

- I have a entity named **Product** with two properties : **$name** and **$price**.
- I create a form related to this entity with all properties.
- I add a new property **$createdAt** in the entity
- The form added automatically a new line : `->add('createdAt')`

Comment: I do not really understand your question. Adding a new property in your entity will not automatically add a new input in your form. You have to do it manually in your form.

Comment: You right, but If I want to add a somes properties in my entity, they are a way to add automatically theses new properties (fields) in the FormType ?

Comment: Not really. There are way to handle form completely dynamically but it's way more complex and prone to errors and not even a good practice.

Comment: And what you think about the way to use addEventListener() : use a loop, to browse and add all properties of an entity ?

Comment: Form events are meant to do dynamic stuff, not to completely create your form. So technically it would not even be needed to use an event to do so, you could just loop through your entity properties and create a form. But I personally would not do something like this. I think it's better to have proper form type because if you need heavy customisation (which is possible thanks to a lot of options) how would you do it by generating your form type based on your entity ? Annotations/Attributes ? You may want to look into easy admin or sonata admin if you want to create crud easier.